# DateTime constructor throws error when the values are OK

Tags: c#

This line:

```
new DateTime(2000, 11, 31, 10, 0, 0)
```

throws error: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

Why is this happening?

Comment: a simple ID-ten-T error from the looks of it

Comment: The exception message explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

november does NOT have 31 days!

Comment: -1: only on earth is this true, he may have been using a Neptunian calender where their years are longer so their months must be too, you cant make the assumption this is based on an earth based calender when giving an answer

Answer (score 7):

November only has 30 days in it.

*There are many ways to remember this... here are two:*

**Poem**

http://askville.amazon.com/poem-remember-days-month/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=6262594

**Knuckle Method**

I personally can't ever remember the poem, but the knuckle method is easy to remember:
http://lifehacker.com/232828/macgyver-tip-use-your-knuckles-to-remember-each-months-days

The knuckle method can be summed up as follows:

1. Make a fist and point it away from you, palm down.
2. Looking at your fist, you should see a row of four knuckles.
3. It should look like **knuckle**-*valley*-**knuckle**-*valley*-**knuckle**-*valley*-**knuckle**.
4. If you start listing the months while touching the knuckles and the valleys, then every month that lands on a knuckle has 31 days.
5. Once you get to the last knuckle ( for July ), start over at the first knuckle ( for August ).

The knuckles have 31 days, the valleys have 30, except for February.

Comment: How about the 'if DateTime throws exception' method? :)

Answer (score 3):

November never has 31 days.

No such date.

In the same way, you can't have a February 29th most years... It is only valid on leap years (so OK for 2012, but you can't create a 29/02/2013 as a `DateTime`).

Comment: wait is this why new DateTime(1800 BC, 13, 33, 25, 61, 61) didnt work for me?

Comment: @RhysW - What kind of number is `1800 BC`? Doesn't compile. And did you look at the [minimum value a DateTime can take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx)?

Comment: sarcasm buddy :) there is no 13th month, 33rd day, 25 hour, 61st minute or 61st second either ;)

Comment: @RhysW - Shame we don't have a tag for that ;)